# i am facing this Supplied connection object Parameter is invalid while i tried to insert data in db2

Tags: database, flask, db2, connection, ibm-cloud

i tried to insert the data into db 2 but shows stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn,insert_sql)
Exception: Supplied connection object Parameter is invalid

my code is

```
def register():
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        address = request.form['address']
        mobileNo = request.form['mobileNo']
        email = request.form['email']
       
        insert_sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
        stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn,insert_sql)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 2, username)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 3, password)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 4, address)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 5, mobileNo)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 6, email)
            
        ibm_db.execute(stmt)
        error = 'You have successfully registered !'
    return render_template('register.html', error = error)
```

```
def register():
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        address = request.form['address']
        mobileNo = request.form['mobileNo']
        email = request.form['email']
       
        insert_sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
        stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn,insert_sql)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 2, username)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 3, password)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 4, address)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 5, mobileNo)
        ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 6, email)
            
        ibm_db.execute(stmt)
        error = 'You have successfully registered !'
    return render_template('register.html', error = error)
```

result is : stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn,insert_sql)
Exception: Supplied connection object Parameter is invalid

Comment: Parameters are enumerated starting from 1, not from 2. Isn't it a type, when you `prepare` with the `stmt` variable, but use `prep_stmt` in `bind_param` instead of `stmt`?

Comment: Also, in addition to the above remarks, the immediate error is clear, you "conn" variable is either not initialised correctly or you have no connection to the database. You should edit your question to show how you verified you have a successful connection to the database.